# symbols next to extension versions

Tags: extension

I've just done a test updgrade from CiviCRM 5.35.1 to 5.46.2 and notice some new symbols next to the version number for extension on the extension management page.  I'm sure the green tick is a good thing but I can't find out what the orange symbol means.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It means the author has listed it as alpha. It's a lab beaker, as in "experimental".

The exact criteria are:

- develStage in the extension's info.xml is not "stable", OR
- version in info.xml contains one of alpha/beta/dev

There is also some hover text: "This is a pre-release version. For more details, see the expanded description."

Comment: useful and has pionted me to the expanded information that I hadn't noticed before.